# AngularJS Filter: Filter the objects with unique ID into separate Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am developing angular app, there i am having the data objects with key and value see below

```
var data=[{key:"home",value:"hk1"},{key:"home",value:"hk2"},{key:"home",value:"hk3"},{key:"home",value:"hk4"},
                            {key:"product",value:"pk1"},{key:"product",value:"pk2"},{key:"product",value:"pk3"},{key:"product",value:"pk4"},
                            {key:"service",value:"sk1"},{key:"service",value:"sk2"},{key:"service",value:"sk3"},{key:"service",value:"sk4"},
                            ];
```

My Page is

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular Boiler Plate</title>
        <script src="/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
        function mainCtrl($scope){
            $scope.Maindata=[{key:"home",value:"hk1"},{key:"home",value:"hk2"},{key:"home",value:"hk3"},{key:"home",value:"hk4"},
                            {key:"product",value:"pk1"},{key:"product",value:"hk2"},{key:"product",value:"hk3"},{key:"product",value:"hk4"},
                            {key:"service",value:"sk1"},{key:"service",value:"hk2"},{key:"service",value:"hk3"},{key:"service",value:"hk4"},
                            ];


        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

        <h2 ng-repeat="data in Maindata" class="">
            {{data.key}}
            <div ng-repeat="">{{data.value}}</div>
        </h2>


    </body>
</html>
```

I want to separate the objects with same key into one separate object like

```
var filtereddata=[{"home":"[{value:"hk1"},{value:"hk2"},{value:"hk3"},{value:"hk4"}]"},
                  {"product":"[{value:"pk1"},{value:"pk2"},{value:"pk3"},{value:"pk4"}]"},
                  {"service":"[{value:"sk1"},{value:"sk2"},{value:"sk3"},{value:"sk4"}]"},
                 ]
```

So that i can use "home", 'service" and "product" as headers one time in a page and iterate those values present in each header into list using ng-repeat.

Here i am going to use two  `ng-repeat` one for headers i.e home, service and product. Another to iterate data in each header.

Please help me achieve this using filter. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot use Plunker at the moment for a demo (GitHub signin problem)

**EDIT:** I created a JSBIN for a live demo: http://jsbin.com/uzUtifi/1/edit?html,js,output

**EDIT:** Using a filter and specifying the key you want to list as keyToDisplay

**js**

```
 $scope.keyToDisplay = 'home';
```

**html**

```
<h2 ng-repeat="data in Maindata | filter:{'key':keyToDisplay}" >
    {{data.key}}
    <div ng-repeat="">{{data.value}}</div>
</h2>
```

**Previous**

If you can include the lodash library (http://lodash.com/), you could rework how your data is formatted before using it in your ng-repeat.

Ex: Using _.groupBy (http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)

```
var data = [
    {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"home",value:"hk4"},
    {key:"product",value:"pk1"},
    {key:"product",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"product",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"product",value:"hk4"},
    {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk2"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk3"},
    {key:"service",value:"hk4"},
];

$scope.filteredData = _.groupBy(data, 'key');
```

FilteredData should look like this:

```
{
    "home": [
        {key:"home",value:"hk1"},
        {key:"home",value:"hk2"},
        {key:"home",value:"hk3"},
        {key:"home",value:"hk4"}
    ],
    "product": [
        {key:"product",value:"pk1"},
        {key:"product",value:"hk2"},
        {key:"product",value:"hk3"},
        {key:"product",value:"hk4"}
    ],
    "service": [
        {key:"service",value:"sk1"},
        {key:"service",value:"hk2"},
        {key:"service",value:"hk3"},
        {key:"service",value:"hk4"},
    ]
};
```

Then you can do:

```
<h2 ng-repeat="data in filteredData.home">
    {{data.key}}
    <div ng-repeat="">{{data.value}}</div>
</h2>
```

to show only the home values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is loadash is framework or plugin in angular?

Comment: It is a separate library helper to work with objects, arrays, and collections! You just have to add it with a script tag as you did for angular. You can download it here: https://raw.github.com/lodash/lodash/2.2.1/dist/lodash.min.js

Comment: not able to read the content in the lodash site, as it is showing me some issue in my browser.

Comment: Right-click the link and Save As on your computer, then add a script tag to your html: <script src="lodash.min.js"></script>

Comment: I added another way using a filter without lodash, look at my edited answer.

Comment: I created a JSBIN for a live demo showing how you can achieve this in various ways!

Comment: Thanks for the Demo, it clearly explains me the different way to do it. i am new to angular and i am having doubt in the code "ng-options="key as key.key for key in keys"" how it works? Could you please explain to me or share some reference link to see this concept.

Comment: Sure, ng-options is like a special ng-repeat only for the select element. So, for `ng-options="key as key.key for key in keys`, it means (left to right) that we want to have the `key` object as the value of the selected option, but we want to display its `key` property for the item `key` in the list of `keys`. I should have named it otherwise! (ie: "item as item.key for item in keys") You can find the doc here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:select

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this but it should work this way in principles.

```
var filteredData = Array();

// helper function to check whether a key
// has already been added to the filteredData 
// array. If yes, return the index. -1 if no
function keyIndex(key, filteredData) {
    for(var i=0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
        if (key in filteredData[i]) {
            return i;
        }   
    };       
    return -1; 
}

// loop through main data and cosntruct the filtered one
$.each($scope.Maindata, function() {
    var index = keyIndex(this.key, filteredData);
    if (index > 0) {
        filteredData[index][this.key].push({"value" : this.value});
    } else {
        filteredData.push({this.key : [{"value" : this.value}]});
    }   
});
```